# How to display all data in field (combobox) on form when rowsource of combo box does not include this value

Tags: ms-access, combobox

Data previously entered into field not displayed when field on form is a combobox control

Have a form that displays information about an event. It includes the name of the staff member who initially set it up. The Combo box rowsource for this control is a list of current staff members only. If the original staff member who set up event has left (ie not current) the control shows a blank when form is opened on that record.

I want to know how to display historical (ie any/all data) but if user wants to change anything they only get the current (ie updated) list available to them.

The control stores the staff ID, the combo box displays the staff name (linked from the staff table. So when try to change the options it says I can't as the bound column is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t have a lot of great choices here.

You of course cannot delete such records since as you point out, such history data will thus break.

There are a few suggestions I can think of.

First up, add the “active” staff column to the combo box display. Then if a user changes or chooses from the combo box, you can prevent (or warn) that they are selecting a non existing staff member. This would display non active staff, but would in theory allow users to select in-active staff – you might not want this. (but you could warn, or prevent in the control before update if you want to prevent this).

Another way is to dynamic load the combo box based on the current record. In other words, if the form is in say “add mode”, or the combo box is blank, then you load up the combo box with a select statement that only includes StaffActive = True.

The above can work rather well if you limit your “main” form to one record (I tend to do this). I tend to present a search form and THEN always launch the main form to ONE record.

So in the forms on-load event, you could check if the column id of the staff is set, and if not active, then you load up the combo box with all staff.

If the column has a staff memember that is active, then in the form on-load, you set the sql of the combo box to only active members.

This approach is “tricky” if you allow record navigation. In that case, you have to put the testing in the on-current event, and set the sql of the combo box that way. Hopefully the staff list table is “small”.

The 3rd way to fill a combo box is by using call backs. This is a LITTLE known approach, and again with on-current event, you could test for the id being a non active and thus set a vatriable (likely global) that allows the call back code to include non active staff.

However, if you stored “id” in that column of a staff record that no longer exists, then there is not a lot you can do. (I would perhaps attempt to re-enter the deleted staff with the correct id’s).

So it not clear if the staff record is deleted, or you have some “active” flag. If you have an active flag, then you can “test” if the staff “id” from the combo box is a non active staff, and then shove the correct sql into the combo box data source that includes the non active staff.

I suppose for performance reasons, and some reduced “flicker”, then I would perhaps set/track what the current combo box is displaying, and ONLY update the combo box if the status (non active) members are required.

Comment: Thankyou, yes, this answers a lot. The forms that have the combo's are only ever opened as one record so I will use your method of testing for an empty field. The staff that are no longer current are not deleted but have a flag as no longer being current. 

And thanks for explaining so clearly. I've followed a lot of your posts so looks like I'm on the right track with the data structure. Cheers.